# why dialog box disapear when search button pressed

Tags: android, dialog

In my application i am trying to open a dialog box when activity started and it has a positive button. on click on that button a new activity will open. Its working fine with following code. But when I long press menu button or search button dialog box get disappear. how can I make this dialog box remain constant even if i press menu or search button. thanks.

```
public class Sam3Activity extends Activity {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.main);


    TextView title = new TextView(this);
    title.setText("DM2");
    title.setBackgroundColor(Color.DKGRAY);
    title.setPadding(10, 10, 10, 10);
    title.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
    title.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
    title.setTextSize(20);
    /* alert message */
    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setCustomTitle(title);

    builder.setMessage("dialog with message").setCancelable(false).setPositiveButton(
            "Ok", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int id) {
                    dialog.dismiss();
                    Log.d("choose","on dissmiss");
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),
                                                              StatisticDisplay.class));//second activity
                }
            });
    AlertDialog alert = builder.create();

    alert.show();
     }
}
```

Comment: sorry i was bit late in checking response.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Take care of the Keys pressed by attaching an `onKeyListener` to the `Dialog`, in my example I'm just taking care of the search key, but you should get the point. In case you've never worked with listeners like this, returning `true` means the event should **not** propagate and is therefor taken care of preventing the system from catching the `search` key when pressed while showing the dialog.

In any other case (the key not being the `KEYCODE_SEARCH`), it will just pass this listener as if it didn't exist. :)

```
... 
builder.setOnKeyListener(new OnKeyListener(){
            @Override
            public boolean onKey(DialogInterface dialog, 
                                 int keyCode,
                                 KeyEvent event) {
                if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_SEARCH ) return true;
                return false;
            }
        });
...
```

Relevant documentation:

- [KeyEvent](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/KeyEvent.html)